# How do I change the thing under the crosshair back to normal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So you know the thingy under the crosshair in Minecraft? My brothers' friend played on my PC and he changed the settings so the bar under the crosshair isn't there anymore but instead it isn't a bar and it is a sword that charges but it is next to my hotbar.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the menu **Options** → **Video Settings**.
2. There will be an option that currently says **Attack Indicator: Hotbar**.

   [image]
3. Click it until it says **Attack Indicator: Crosshair** instead.